# Put object fields into a map

Tags: apex, map

I have a method that searches an object with a unique key and then takes that ID and populates a field on the Product object. This seems to work as I can pass the value from a trigger handler to a helper class, then the logic finds the record and updates the product.

The next step that if there is no record found I want to pass the product's information to a map so in a different method I can create a new object record. I think I need to put an if a record is returned do the update else put the info into a map to be handed off. However, I cannot figure out how to do it with the correct syntax

Is there a good way to do this?

```
public static void existingBundleSearch(map<String, List<Product2>> mapProductIdentifier)
{
    // Query on product bundle object and update the all the product 'Product_Bundle__c' lookup with Product_Bundle__c id
    Map<Id, Product2> prods = new Map<Id, Product2>();
    List<Product2> prodUpdate = new List<Product2>(); // list of products to Update
    for(Product_Bundle__c prodBundle: [ SELECT  Id,
                                                Product_Identifier__c
                                        FROM Product_Bundle__c 
                                        WHERE Product_Identifier__c IN: mapProductIdentifier.keySet()])
    {
        for(Product2 prod : mapProductIdentifier.get(prodBundle.Product_Identifier__c))
        {
            //if(!prodBundle.size() = 0)
            {
                prodUpdate.add(new Product2(
                    Id = prod.Id, 
                    Product_Bundle__c = prodBundle.Id
                ));
            //} else{
            //  prods.putAll(prod);
            }
        }
    }
        update prodUpdate;
        createBundle(prods);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question:-

```
for(Product2 prod : mapProductIdentifier.get(prodBundle.Product_Identifier__c))
{
    if(prod != null && ! mapProductIdentifier.get(prodBundle.Product_Identifier__c).size()==0)
    {
        prodUpdate.add(new Product2(
            Id = prod.Id, 
            Product_Bundle__c = prodBundle.Id
        ));
    //} else{
    //  prods.putAll(prod);
    }
    else
    {
        prods.put(prod.id,prod)
    }
}
```

`prod.id` is going to be unique so, it would not create issues.